# why is my global variable still the same after update

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables, python-telegram-bot

i am creating a telegram bot using python and i can't update the global variable in the callback function please help

i have tried to updated the variable using global FLAG inside a callback function but the variable is still the same

```
FLAG = 0

def start_all(bot,update):

    global FLAG
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id

    FLAG = 0

    sell = telegram.KeyboardButton(text="buy")

    buy = telegram.KeyboardButton(text="sell")

    custom_keyboard =[[ sell, buy ]]

    reply_markup = telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
            custom_keyboard)

    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id,
            text="Thank you",
            reply_markup=reply_markup
            )


    command= update.effective_message.text 




    if command == "buy":
        buy = Buy()
        FLAG = 1

        buy.start(bot,update)

    elif command == "sell":
        sell = Sell()
        FLAG = 2

        sell.start(bot,update)

    else:
        #help
        pass

def main():

    updater = Updater('')

    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('test',test))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start',start_all))

    if FLAG == 1:
        buy = Buy()
        dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.location, 
        buy.start))
    elif FLAG == 2:
        sell = Sell()
        dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.location, sell.insert_user_to_database)) 

    elif FLAG == 0:

        dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, start_all)) 


    else:
        pass
```

i expected the FLAG will be 1 when i click buy ,2 when i click sell and check if i clicked buy or sell in main function and handle the filters accordingly

Comment: The `global FLAG` should have worked. Could you please confirm if you are getting the expected values in `command variable`, as the value of `FLAG` is dependent on the value of `comment variable`.

Comment: i tried but it has the same value . if you know
 how to handle two filters separetly for example if i have
 dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.location, buy.start))
 dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.location,to_database))
i dont want both the handlers fire i don't have to use global var if i can solve this problem

Comment: Have you checked whether your IF-statement parses correctly? I suspect that Flag simply isn't checked because the IF-statement always evaluates to ```pass``. For testing purposes print-out ```command``` to see whether it actually is 'buy' or 'sell'.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the IF statement is incorrect here. Telegram `update.message.text` is not a string so the evaluation will always fail and go to `pass`.

Try changing it to:

```py
command = str(update.message.text)
```

Edit:

Additionally it seems to me you should be using a query-structure like this:

```py
def start(update, context):
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("BUY", callback_data='buy'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("SELL", callback_data='sell')],
               ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('WANT TO BUY OR SELL?', reply_markup=reply_markup)

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

def flag(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    command = str(update.callback_query.data)
    if command == 'buy':
        FLAG = 1
        #do stuff
    elif command == 'sell':
        FLAG = 2
        #do stuff
    else:
        pass

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(flag))
```